# iPhone backup is too small even though iCloud is disabled

Tags: iphone, itunes, backup, windows, bug

I am trying to help my mom.

I am aware that iPhone local backups can be smaller due to some photos and whatnot being stored in iCloud. However, that doesn't seem to be the case here. iCloud photo backup is disabled and still a brand new backup is about the size of the photo library alone:

`Photo library: 9.49 GB`

`Apps: 287.8 MB`

`Documents and Data: 5.98 GB` (**what's included here? Notes? There is definitely not 6 GB of notes here, not even 100 MB**)

`Other: 1.92` (**what is "other"?**)

So, the total should be about 17.67 GB.
Meanwhile, the backup is only:

`Size: 9.7 GB`

`Size on disk: 9.71 GB`

I.e., the backup is barely the size of the photo library alone.

When she had a backup restore on an old phone a couple years ago, my mom says some of her text messages didn't get restored.

What's going on here??